# Calling multiple selectors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When one needs to grab multiple nodes. Lets say I want to append a couple of nodes. For example sake: 2 nodes them being:

```
<div id=”one”>
    <button class="btn">button</button> 
</div>

<div id=”two”>
</div>
```

In JavaScript one would need to grab both elements, logically we simply something like (eg):

```
// Get
this.element = document.getElementById('one');
this.appTo = document.getElementById('two');

//append
this.appTo.appendChild(this.element, this.appTo);
```

However, I don't like the fact I am calling `document.getElementById` 2 times, how does one better handle something like this? to go a little further with this, Let's say I want to modifying an element nested within the `one`  div before appending it to `two` – then in this situation I generally work my way down the nodes using the parent as the selector eg:

```
// Getting element with class .btn and changing txt color:
this.button = this.element.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
this.button.style.color = '#000000';
```

At this level, I feel as if it's ok to call  `document.getElementById();` two times, but when these types of apps grow I see myself calling element selectors way to f*cking much, it feels hacky and I would love to know how to handle element selector heavy components and a little bit more about the downsides to calling repeated `document.getElementById();` or similar?

Do I just wrap these in functions? or is it ok to keep this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are answering your question in the tags you provide, namely jQuery. jQuery gives you the tools to quickly interact with the DOM.

For example:

```
this.element = document.getElementById('one');
this.appTo = document.getElementById('two');
```

Becomes:

```
this.element = $('#one');
this.appTo = $('#two');
```

Modifying elements is also much easier:

```
// Getting element with class .btn and changing txt color:
this.button = this.element.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
this.button.style.color = '#000000';
```

Becomes:

```
$('.btn').first().css('color', '#000000');
```

You can even modify multiple elements, for example all elements with class `btn`, with a single line:

```
$('.btn').css('color', '#000000');
```

Performance wise, jQuery uses the native javascript methods under the hood, so it will be a little slower. For most common uses however, bad performance is more likely caused by bad programming than jQuery being slow.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the "question". The OP is making the observation that using ID selectors feels "hacky", and to that you've suggested to use jQuery?

Comment: I don't think he's saying that using ID selectors is bad per se. To me it seems he finds the built in javascript methods for manipulating the DOM ugly and awkward to use. Using jQuery would make DOM manipulation a lot less painful for him.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is right on this one, I don't see the need for jQuery and or most JS frameworks, I more so mean is it better to wrap these selector calls within a function opposed to calling them everytime. 

After some more research, it doesn't really matter but I would love someone to clear it up. I really appreciate your input, but jQuery imo hold the web back and new generation developers. Far too often people know jQuery and not JavaScript. with ES6 jQuery is not something we need with the modern web.

Comment: @panoply In that case, you might want to take a look at Angular, or the more light weight Vue JS. These frameworks focus on efficient DOM manipulation, and they severely reduce the amount of DOM queries you will be making. There's a bit of a learning curve there, but surely that's no problem for somebody that's part of the new generation of developers, who don't want to be held back by 'outdated technology' like jQuery.